# Obtain lines of a file beginning with a prefix

Tags: c, fopen, getline, plaintext, strncmp

I am trying to detect which lines of my plaintext start with "linePrefix". Using the code above, even when there is a coincidence, `strcmp` never returns 0. Does anyone know where am I failing?

```
  const char PREFIX[] = {"linePrefix"};
  FILE *fp;
  char *line = NULL;
  char *aux = NULL;
  aux = (char *) malloc(16);
  size_t len = 0;
  ssize_t read;
  char path[] = {/*path*/};

  fp = fopen(path, "r");

  while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
    strncpy(aux, line, 15);
    printf("strcmp: %i\n, strcmp(aux, PREFIX));
  }
```

Comment: [Please don't cast the result of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/3233393).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to add the string terminator on `aux`:

```
strncpy(aux, line, 15);
aux[15] = `\0`;
```

Note that there is a simpler way to do the comparison where you don't need to copy the string. Just compare with the beginning of `line` directly:

```
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
  printf("strcmp: %i\n, strncmp(line, PREFIX, strlen(PREFIX)));
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion, though instead of `strlen(PREFIX)` use `sizeof(PREFIX)-1`.

Comment: @Lundin That'll work as long as PREFIX is declared as an array.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Any reason why it wouldn't be? You may as well write `sizeof("linePrefix")-1` but that would make the code ugly.

Comment: `const char *PREFIX = "tag"` would break it. On the other hand, if the optimizer doesn't replace the strlen call with a constant and performance is crucial, then it's definitely worth using `sizeof` to shave off an unnecessary length count.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the lines are longer than 15 characters, in which case strncpy() breaks. strncpy behaves as:

> If the array pointed to by s2 is a string that is shorter than n characters, null characters
>   are appended to the copy in the array pointed to by s1, until n characters in all have been
>   written.

In other words, if there is no room, strncpy will not null terminate the program, causing it to crash and burn. Therefore, avoid strncpy(), it is a dangerous function that programmers often fail to use correctly.

Better code:

```
size_t length = strlen(line);

if(length > MAX_LENGTH)
{
  length = MAX_LENGTH;
}

memcpy(aux, line, length);
aux[length] = '\0';
```